Consider $f$ differentiable on $(0,1)$. If $f$ is not linear, then $\exists \ y : (0,1) : \left|\frac{f'(y)}{f(1) - f(0)}\right| > 1$.
Suppose $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$. Prove that if $f$ is not linear, then $\exists \ y : (0,1) : \left|\frac{f'(y)}{f(1) - f(0)}\right| > 1$.
By LMVT, $\exists$ $t : (0,1) : f(1) - f(0) = f'(t)$. We now need to show that $\exists$ $y : (0,1) : |f'(y)| < |f'(t)|$.
How do I proceed from here?
I thought of tackling every single $(f(t) \lesseqgtr 0, f'(t) \lesseqgtr 0)$ case, but it didn't work out in the end.

The contrapositive should be easier to prove

Suppose $|f'(t)|\le |f(1)-f(0)|$ for all $t$. Then MVT shows $|f(x)-f(y) |\le |x-y| C$ where $C=|f(1)-f(0)|$.
Now, if $f(1)-f(0) \ge 0$,  then  $f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^{1}f'(t)dt \le \int_0^{1} [f(1)-f(0)]dt=f(1)-f(0)$. Hence equality must hold throughout forcing $f'(t)$ to be $ [f(1)-f(0)]$ for almost all $t$.  Hence $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x}f'(t)dt=f(0)+[f(1)-f(0)]x$ for all $x$.
For the case $f(1)-f(0) \le 0$ apply the argument to $-f$.

What do you mean by "if the conclusion fails"?

@adamsmaple I hope the proof is now clear.

How do you justify $f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^{1} f'(t)dt$? Do you assume that $f'$ is continuous?

@MartinR $f$ is actually Lipschitz, so the proof is valid without continuity of $f'$.

Assume that $|f'(y)| \le |f(1) - f(0)|$ for all $y \in (0, 1)$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $f(0) \le f(1)$, so that
$$
\forall y \in (0, 1) :f'(y) \le f(1) - f(0) \, .
$$
The idea is to prove that the graph of $f$ lies below and above the straight line from $(0, f(0))$ to $(1, f(1))$.
For $x \in (0, 1)$ is
$$
  f(x) = f(0) + (f(x)-f(0)) = f(0) + x f'(y_1) 
$$
for some $y_1 \in (0, x)$, so that
$$ \tag{1}
f(x) \le f(0) + x (f(1) - f(0)) \, .
$$
Also
$$
 f(x) = f(1) - (f(1) - f(x)) = f(1) - (1-x)f'(y_2) 
$$
for some $y_2 \in (1, x)$, so that
$$
\tag{2}
f(x) \ge f(1) - (1-x)(f(1) -   f(0))  = f(0) + x (f(1) - f(0)) \, .
$$
So we have
$$
f(0) + x (f(1) - f(0)) \overset{(2)}{\le} f(x) \overset{(1)}{\le} f(0) + x (f(1) - f(0))
$$
and therefore
$$
 f(x) = f(0) + x (f(1) - f(0)) \, ,
$$
i.e. $f$ is linear.
